# Food Ingredient API/Database

Tags: food

For a project I need a data source, where I can find informations about ingredients like lactic acid or E 901. The needed information is if the searched ingredient can cause food allergies, is vegan, vegetarian, kosher, etc.

I could not find something like this in the last hour, only recipe information by name and/or barcode.

Use case: Check if a list of ingredients for a food will be suitable for people with dietary restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoonacular's [Food and Recipe API](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/food) provides access to over 360,000 recipes and 80,000 food products. The API enables users to search for recipes using natural language (such as "gluten-free brownies without sugar"). Users can visualize recipe nutrition and ingredient lists, analyze recipe costs, find recipes by nutritional requirements, favorite ingredients, or what's in the refrigerator, classify recipes, convert ingredient amounts, and even compute an entire meal plan. The service covers ingredients, recipes, food products, and menu items.
*spoonacular Food API includes a Visualize Recipe Nutrition feature.[spoonacular](https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs/visualize-recipe-nutrition)*

---

[ESHA Nutrition Database API](https://esha.com/products/nutrition-database-api/)

The ESHA Nutrition API is designed to simplify the integration of your application with ESHA’s extensive food database and nutritional standards. Rather than developing and maintaining your own nutrient database, you can rely on ESHA for high-quality source data.

**How this works**

When a user searches for a food item on your website or application, a list of selections meeting the search criteria is returned. The user selects the closest match, enters a quantity and measure, and adds the item to the list. From there, the user can view a nutrition breakdown of total Calories, Fat, Protein, and other nutrients.

With, developers can design an application that accesses the ESHA database and nutritional standards. The application can search over 100,000 foods, build a recipe or food intake with the results, analyze up to 80 nutrients in seconds, and view client nutrient recommendations expressed as DRIs, DGAs, or RDIs.

**Extensive Database**

Our database boasts over 100,000 unique foods, including raw ingredients, recipes, manufacturers’ foods, processing items, more.

**Food Analysis**

Analyze foods for up to 80 nutrients and nutrient factors – everything from Calories and Fats to MyPlate values.

**Recommendations**

You can analyze dietary intakes per nutritional recommendations specified by various standards such as DRI, DGA, and RDI.

---

[Food Database API Documentation](https://developer.edamam.com/food-database-api-docs)

**Food Database**

This API provides you with tools to find nutrition and diet data for generic foods, packaged foods, and restaurant meals. In addition, it employs NLP (Natural Language Processing) which allows for the extraction of food entities from unstructured text.

**Covered Use Cases**

- Search for food by keyword, food name or UPC/Barcode
- Sourcing of nutrition facts for a given food, including macro and micronutrients, allergen labels, lifestyle and health labels
- Search for food by given nutrient quantity for 28 nutrients
- Seach for foods within a given brand
- With the built-in food-logging context it allows for NLP requests for chatbots and natural language calorie counters

Parse requests: https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser

---

[Edamam’s Recipe Search API](http://developer.edamam.com) which features 1.5 million recipes -
All recipes contain nutrition facts and are tagged with diet, health, and allergy labels. Recipes are searchable by keywords and ingredients. There is a free plan available.

The database is available for free noncommercial use and free commercial use for startups

---

**More Resources**

- [10 Most Popular Food APIs](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/10-most-popular-food-apis/brief/2019/08/06)
- [Food-Related APIs](https://rapidapi.com/collection/food-apis)

  - Check out this collection of Food APIs, including ingredients, nutrition, recipes, allergies, restaurants, and more!
- [Programmableweb](https://www.programmableweb.com/category/food/api)
- [APIlist](https://apilist.fun/category/food)